# using JQuery to cycle through [same_class_name] elements, then append some text to each one based on its value

Tags: jquery, html, dom

My HTML looks like this :

```
<li class="price">
  <em>29.00</em>
  <span class="shipping">Shipping:12.00</span>
  <span class="comments"></span>
</li>

<li class="price">
  <em>12.00</em>
  <span class="shipping">Shipping:4.00</span>
  <span class="comments"></span>
</li>
```

This pattern repeats around 9-15 times on the page.

I want to extract the two numbers (in the first `<li>` for example, it's 29.00 and also 12.00) and add them to one another (29+12=41), multiply the result by 2, then add a new element showing that result (after each `<li>`).

Of course, each `<li>` should have its own result.

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Finally got the whole thing to working together !

### (BIG thanks to dasfisch & Barmar) :

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var finalPrice = 0;

jQuery('.price').each(function(i) {
    var myProductPrice = parseFloat(jQuery(this).children('em').html());
    var myShippingPriceString = jQuery(this).children('.shipping').html();

//find the numeric portion of the string (decimal number)
var re = new RegExp();
re.compile("([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)");
var myShippingPrice = parseFloat(myShippingPriceString.match(re)[0]);

finalPrice = ((myProductPrice+myShippingPrice)*2).toString(); //your maths

jQuery(this).append('<li>  product price: ' + myProductPrice + '</li>');
jQuery(this).append('<li>  shipping price: ' + myShippingPrice + '</li>');
jQuery(this).append('<li>  ==============</li>');
jQuery(this).append('<li>  final price: ' + finalPrice + '</li>'); //change this to whatever HTML you want; the append is the important part
jQuery(this).append('<br><br>');
});

});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why aren't you using jQuery's built in functions to traverse the DOM?

Try this:

```
var finalPrice = 0;

jQuery('.price').each(function(i) {
    var myProductPrice = parseFloat(jQuery(this).children('em').html());
    var myShippingPrice = parseFloat(jQuery(this).children('.shipping').html()); // you need to strip out the Shipping: text, too.

    finalPrice = ((myProductPrice+myShippingPrice)*2).toString(); //your maths

    jQuery('.yourUlElement').append('<li>' + finalPrice + '</li>'); //change this to whatever HTML you want; the append is the important part
});
```

Comment: Simple, Elegant, Brilliant ! :-)
Many thanks mate.

Regarding the way to strip the "shipping" text from the number,
What would you suggest ?

Comment: Is it always the same string `"Shipping:"`? Then you can use the Javascript `substring()` function to get the number after it. If there's a pattern to the prefix, use a regex.

Comment: i'd rather not count on it (that it will always be "Shipping:") so I tried using regex but the script stopped working. Seems like something is wrong in the "match" expression : 
     
var myShippingPrice = myShippingPriceString.match((?:^|(?<=\s))[0-9]*\.?[0-9](?=\s|$));
    
   
http://jsfiddle.net/swLTc/8/

Comment: Finally got the whole thing to working together !
(BIG thanks to dasfisch & Barmar).  
  
    //find the numeric portion of the string (decimal number)
    var re = new RegExp();
    re.compile("([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)");
    var myShippingPrice = parseFloat(myShippingPriceString.match(re)[0]);